# Pass String from Activity to Fragment (Null)

Tags: android

I am trying to pass Data from Activity to Fragment, but passing information is still NULL. What am i doing wrong?

**Activity**

```java
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("data", "hello");
BiezaceAwarie obj = new BiezaceAwarie();
obj.setArguments(bundle);
```

**Fragment**

```java
String abc;
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    abc = getArguments().getString("data");
}
```

Comment: Since I have no idea where your code for fragment is. One problem I can guess is that inside the if block u might want to use this.getArguments().getString("data") instead of getArguments().getString("data").  Though this is just a guess. or maybe u should have just used abc = bundle.getString("data")

Comment: I must add, that this fragment is Tab.